# Add propTypes to function

Tags: reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6

I would like add propTypes to my function in React for passing data.

I use createContainer (for Meteor Data) and i would like passing my Data for test if user is logged and if is admin for render my component.

My AdminLayout (using in my React Router) :

```
const AdminLayout = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {

  console.log(AdminContainer)

  if (AdminLayout === true) {

    return (
      <Route {...rest} render={matchProps => (
        <div className="app-container">
          <HeaderAdmin />
            <main className="l-main">
              <Component {...matchProps} />
            </main>
          <FooterAdmin />
        </div>
      )} />
    )

  } else {
    return (
      <Redirect push to="/connexion"/>
    )
  }
};

AdminLayout.propTypes = {
  isLogged: React.PropTypes.bool,
  isAdmin: React.PropTypes.bool
}

AdminContainer = createContainer(() => {
  const isLogged = Meteor.userId();
  const isAdmin = Meteor.call('is-admin', Meteor.userId(), function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  });

  return {
    isLogged,
    isAdmin
  };
}, AdminLayout);

export default AdminLayout;
```

My `console.log()` return juste `function ReactMeteorData()` :/ I don't know how i can passing my data in my function.

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you community !

Comment: can you recreate a repo with minimal code that produce the same error?

Comment: Ok, i edit my first post in 10m, thank you :)

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific as to what you are trying to achieve? The `AdminContainer` that you are logging contains the react component wrapped by `react-meteor-data`, as it should.

Comment: There are so many things wrong here, no offsense, but I believe you copypasted a bunch of code at random. Anyway, calling `Meteor.call` in `createContainer` will never work, because it doesn't return a value right away. Also, `if (AdminLayout === true)` just makes no sense whatsoever. For rights management in Meteor you could use the `alanning:roles` package, that one should work nicely with `createContainer`.